# Android: android: trying to refresh list view after data is loaded in background

Tags: android

I'm using an `AsyncTask` to load in data for a `ListView`.

After the data is loaded I'm calling the `invalidate()` method of the `ListView`, but it doed not get redrawn.  I put break points on the call back of the array adapter's `getView()` method. It never gets called after the invalidate.  But does get called after the `ListView` is first created.

Right now to test it I use a global verbal called `cGlobals.gSay` to be displayed in the list book

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
  mReady=true;
  UpdateList();
  if (result.compareTo("na")==0)
    NextLevel();          
}

void UpdateList()
{
  cGlobals.gSay= new String("aaaaaaaaa");
  listView.postInvalidate();      
}
```

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;  
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(cGlobals.gSay);
    return row;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you updating the list for MySimpleArrayAdapter? Please post this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method that is available in your `MySimpleArrayAdapter`.

Only caveat is that for the ListView to update using this approach, you must be modifying the data that is in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call this instead of invalidate

```
ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[Link to android ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)